# Laravel: how to connect controller to view without using or defining a route

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to find the route that has connected a view and controller in a code i'm editing. 
This is how route is included in the view.

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.provider.edit', $provider->id) }}" ></i> Edit</a>
```

Comment: That should be the name of the route in your `routes/web.php`

Comment: @Jerodev it could be name ?

Comment: Use `php artisan route:list` and search for the name `admin.provider.edit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
use \App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName;

{{ ControllerName::Functionname($params); }}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your console a run the next command:

`php artisan route:list`

This will output something like this:

[image]

Right there you can see a lot of information such as: Domain, Method, URI, Name, Action and Middleware. That's the best way to find what you want!